# HDF5 grouping/extracting the same data layer from all files in group in R

Tags: r, grouping, hdf5

I am a relatively new R user. I am having problems extracting the same file from several HDF5 files. This is what I did using the  rhdf5 package:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".he5",full.names=TRUE)
```

The file I can't extract from all the HDF5 Files has the extension

```
"/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop"
```

When I run the command below for individual files, it works:

```
NO2he5<-h5read("MA.he5","/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop")
```

How do I translate this to a function that can extract the layer simultaneously for multiple hdf5 files, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `lapply`:

```
library(rhdf5)
files <- list.files(pattern = ".he5", full.names = TRUE)
attribute <- "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop"
out.list <- lapply(files, h5read, attribute)
```

This will store all the read objects into a single object: a list. It is the preferred approach versus creating as many objects as you have files.

Comment: Hi flodel, I just ran it and it returned with the error message below: Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'h5read' not found. I had tried it with the lapply and for some reason its doesn't view it as a command. What could be wrong?

Comment: You need to load the function with `library(rhdf5)`, prior to calling it via `lapply`. Please give it another try.

Comment: Thanks, Flodel. I found out i was opening too many packages at once causing a conflict. I loaded just the rhdf5 library and it worked well.